# QVirtualKeyboard default style for PySide6 and PySide2 not the same

Tags: python, pyside6, qt6, pyqt6, qtvirtualkeyboard

I use the keyboard in the project written on pyside2, without any additional settings it looks like this:

[image]

But the same code on pyside6 displays the keyboard in another style:

[image]

How can I use style from pyside2 in pyside6?

Comment: See the output of `QApplication.style().objectName()` of both versions. If they don't match, see if `QStyleFactory.keys()` of the PySide6 lists the style used in PySide2, and eventually use `QApplication.setStyle(NameOfStyle)`. Otherwise, it means that they changed the look of the keyboard, and there's probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @musicamante The keyboard style does not depend on the QML style or the QtWidgets style

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, you're right, I didn't remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to download the qtvirtualkeyboard style from Qt5 and use it in Qt6:

1. Copy the default style from the Qt5 branch of qtvirtualkeyboard to the `qml/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/` folder next to the .py file with another name.

   ```
   mkdir -p  qml/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/
   git clone -b 5.15.2 https://code.qt.io/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git
   cp -rf qtvirtualkeyboard/src/virtualkeyboard/content/styles/default qml/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/Styles/qt5default
   ```

   The structure should be the following:

   ```
   ├── main.py
   └── qml
       └── QtQuick
           └── VirtualKeyboard
               └── Styles
                   └── qt5default
                       ├── images
                       │   ├── backspace-868482.svg
                       │   ├── check-868482.svg
                       │   ├── enter-868482.svg
                       │   ├── globe-868482.svg
                       │   ├── handwriting-868482.svg
                       │   ├── hidekeyboard-868482.svg
                       │   ├── search-868482.svg
                       │   ├── selectionhandle-bottom.svg
                       │   ├── shift-80c342.svg
                       │   ├── shift-868482.svg
                       │   ├── shift-c5d6b6.svg
                       │   └── textmode-868482.svg
                       ├── style.qml
                       └── virtualkeyboard_default_style.qrc
   ```
2. Change line:

   ```
   readonly property string resourcePrefix: "qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/styles/default/"
   ```

   to:

   ```
   readonly property string resourcePrefix: ""
   ```
3. In the .py you must include the qml to QML_IMPORT_PATH and set QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_STYLE with the new style:

   ```py
   import os
   from pathlib import Path
   import sys

   from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit

   CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

   def main():
       os.environ["QML_IMPORT_PATH"] = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "qml")
       os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
       os.environ["QT_VIRTUALKEYBOARD_STYLE"] = "qt5default"

       app = QApplication(sys.argv)

       w = QLineEdit()
       w.show()

       sys.exit(app.exec())


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```